# variable replacement in WMI method

Tags: vb.net, iis, wmi

I am trying to execute a command that works with hard coded variables, but when I try and replace the name *test* below with *selectedname*, I cannot get the syntax for escaping the command. The basic idea is I am using WMI to query the app pool names and then selecting one and storing in the slectedname variable, which works when I test with a `msgbox(selectedname)` line. It also shows up when I am stepping through, but does not get passed to the bottom command. Any help would be great.
The function where I am trying to execute the command is

```
Private Sub Stpbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Stpbtn.Click

        Dim selectedname As String
        selectedname = RWM_lst1.SelectedItem.ToString
        MsgBox(selectedname)

        Dim strComputer
        Dim objShare
        Dim objWMIService
        Dim objOutParams
        strComputer = "."
        objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\WebAdministration")
        '' Obtain an instance of the the class 
        '' using a key property value.
        objShare = objWMIService.Get("ApplicationPool.Name='test'")

        '' no InParameters to define

        '' Execute the method and obtain the return status.
        '' The OutParameters object in objOutParams
        '' is created by the provider.


        objOutParams = objWMIService.ExecMethod("ApplicationPool.Name='test'", "Stop") -- I know this works with the hard coded value of test
        objOutParams = objWMIService.ExecMethod("ApplicationPool.Name=" & selectedname & ", "Stop") --I want to replace the variable selectedname with the value captured in the selectedname  variable

    End Sub
End Class
```

In Frith,
Devin

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting the variable  `selectedname` like this

```
objOutParams = objWMIService.ExecMethod("ApplicationPool.Name='" & selectedname & "'", "Stop")
```